# Automatically continue in a new column after x-amount of list-items

Tags: php, wordpress, listitem, multiple-columns

I am making a website where I need to have a 3-column list of items. The list is supposed to become a wp_nav that displays 21 items alphabetically, so it should be able to create new columns(ul) by itself.

It currently looks like the code below, but since wordpress is going to load the wp_nav, I can't really figure out how to dynamically make this happen. Is there some way using jquery or php to do this?

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            (+6) ...
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            (+6) ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I'm thinking something like a :nth-child thing, or a php counter.

Comment: This is really more of a presentation issue.  You can come up with a PHP solution but maybe styling a list with CSS to achieve the appearance you want would be a better option.  For example you can make your LI elements inline-block or float: left and set their width to a third of the container to get a 3 column style of layout.

Comment: I could do that but then the list wouldn't be alphabetical the right way (horizontal, while it should be vertical). Possibly as a last resort but I'm still looking for a way to do it like this.